# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/util/MetaAnnotationUtils while running unit tests in Spring 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I am trying to upgrade Spring framework from version 5 to 6 but getting the following error when trying to run the unit tests.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/util/MetaAnnotationUtils
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils
```

I am also not seeing "MetaAnnotationUtils" class under the "spring-test" jar for 6.0.6 under my compiled project. Also I cannot see this class being used anywhere in my test class, hence not sure what to do. Any idea around this ?

Note: I am using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.0.4 and Spring 6 in my current project.

I tried upgrading the project to use Spring 6 and Java 17 as per the requirements of my team.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, did you sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

*org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils is deprecated
as of Spring Framework 5.3 in favor of TestContextAnnotationUtils*

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.13/javadoc-api/deprecated-list.html

The is located at package org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils

In Spring 5 it was deprecated, in Spring 6 it is completely removed and needs to be replaced with TestContextAnnotationUtils.